# Notify the user that the email already exists.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

community, I am developing a user application that you can sign up and log in, I use React, RDX, SQL with the UNIQUE: TRUE property. To avoid repeated emails, in the DDBB it does not accept the mail, but the browser the notice of the email is already registered is not printed on the screen. I do not know if I am skipping a step or the regex is wrongly located in my code I leave my code where is the mail regex. Thanks in advance for any help!

`const [, setError] = useState([]);`

````
axios
  .post("http://localhost:3006/users", body)
  .then((res) => {
    setDatosUser(res.data.results);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      var errorText = err.response.data.message;
        if (errorText?.includes("email")){
              setError(JSON.stringify("El email ya esta registrado."));

        } else if (errorText?.includes("phone")){
              setError(JSON.stringify("El telefono ya esta registrado."));
        }else{
              setError(JSON.stringify(err.response.data.message));
        }
          return Error("Files not Found");
        });
          history.push("/login");```
````

Comment: May be the api is not throwing an exception for you to catch in react. Try to console in both "then" and "catch" functions and see what is returning

Comment: Thanks!!! I'm still looking for the fault

Comment: You're showing the error nowhere. Instead `const [error, setError] = useState([]);` and then render the error somewhere `<div>{error}</div>`. A note, you don't need `JSON.stringify` since it's already string.